# Prevent cut-off lines when using css media @ print

Tags: css

I have the problem when I modify a website's print output:
So, if you go to this link: https://exist.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/2/v/pa000008-0120
and hit [Ctrl+P]  (I don't know about apple :-D ) you should see a 26 page long preview of the so-called Restitutionsedikt.

1. I cannot figure out how to prevent the cut-off line in Line 39. :-/
   I'vre tried to add the following (the display:block; either enabled or disabled; both won't work.

   p{
   /* display:block */
   page-break-inside:auto;
   }

Any hints on how to make this work properly?

All the best,
K
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution can help you

```
@media print {
  * {
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
```

Comment: not perfect, yet. At some points there's still cut-off lines, but better :-) 
Probably play with break-before and break-after values :-D Thank you :-)

Comment: Hmm I think it's the best solution I can think of, let me try to find some better ways

Comment: Hi now that I am back from Covid (it sucks, don't get it!) I am looking at this again ... 
A colleague mentions that this works for Safari but no ther browsers ... 
That's sad, however, I wanted to thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: wow glad that you recovered! Hopefully, your family has stayed well too. Actually, I had tried a few ways, but they didn't work well for unpredicted phrases :( @kev1807

Comment: I found pagedJs (https://pagedjs.org/posts/2021-06-newRelease/ ) which should work for my case, maybe the footnotes will suck, but that might be a trade-off we can live with. (Our work has several footnote sections  -.-) 

everyone is better now, yes. Am easily distracted and out of breath but other than that healthy!